# Appending data below the existing data in csv file Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, csv, opencsv

I have a csv file which contains 14 columns and 5 rows. I'm reading contents of last column and I'm performing some mathematical operation on the column values and saving that in an array named `exposureFactor[]`. Now I have to write that array column wise below the first column skiping a row which is getting done perfectly. But when I run the program again it gives me this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:662)
at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$4$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:212)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:550)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluateToArrayNode(AbstractPipeline.java:260)
at java.base/java.util.stream.IntPipeline.toArray(IntPipeline.java:538)
at com.sajood.Readingcsv.appendCol.main(appendCol.java:28)
```

Can someone please highlight the issue. It's a project given to me and it's deadline is in 2 days.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class appendCol {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int sum = 0;
    String[] data5;
    CSVReader reader5 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\new.csv"));
    String[] nextLine5;
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (null != (nextLine5 = reader5.readNext())) {
        li.add(nextLine5[nextLine5.length - 1]);

    }
    String[] tempe = li.toArray(new String[0]);
    String[] exp = Arrays.copyOfRange(tempe, 1, tempe.length);
    data5 = Arrays.toString(exp).replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\"", "").replace(" ", "").split(",");
    int[] weightage = Arrays.stream(data5).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); 
    for (int i = 0; i < weightage.length; i++) {
        sum += weightage[i];
    }
    int average = sum / 6;
    String averageStr = String.valueOf(average);
    String exposureFactor[] = { "Exposure Factor", averageStr };
    FileWriter writer4 = new FileWriter("D:\\new.csv", true);
    CSVReader reader3 = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\new.csv"), '\t', '\'', 6);
    if ((reader3.readNext()) != null) {
        return;
     } else {
        for (int j = 0; j < exposureFactor.length; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                writer4.append("\n");
            }
            writer4.append(String.valueOf(exposureFactor[j]));
            writer4.append("\n");
        }
        writer4.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please edit your question to include the **complete** stacktrace.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please have look now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only line it could be is:
`int[] weightage = Arrays.stream(data5).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();`

I assume it's trying to parse your blank line as numbers. Why do you need to run it again after you've output your exposure factor?

---

If your boss reeeeeeeally needs to run it twice in a row, the quick fix is to add a try catch and make it exit "gracefully."

```
try {
    int[] weightage = Arrays.stream(data5).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Program has already been run.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You could also use that `if ((reader3.readNext()) != null)` check if you feel like reworking things.

---

One more thing: you might want `average` to be a `double` instead of an `int`.

Comment: I'm converting this to int[] because I want to perform operation the values. I can't perform that on String[]

Comment: Right. Then you perform the operation on that int[], and a blank line and "Exposure Factor" are added to new.csv. Then you run it a second time, and it tries to read that blank line as a list of numbers, which fails. Why do you need to run it that second time?

Comment: and also the value of exposure factor is written below the "Exposure Factor". Your point is correct that I don't need to run it again but my project lead asked to resolve it and I'm stuck at it from pas week. Can't I do something with this block of code like any condition or something that just run it once and then never when program is run ?

Comment: Just tell it like it is! But if he reeeeeally needs it to exit gracefully instead of blowing up, surround that `weightage` line with try/catch. I'll edit my answer with a code snippet.